# HtmlPurifier: Display hostnames only with Linkify

Tags: php, anchor, htmlpurifier, linkify

Of course you've might heard about [HtmlPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/). I'm using linkify functionality - automatically convert urls to `a` tags. So, now I want to display only hostnames but leave full url in `href` attribute.

Example:

`http://www.website.com/article/123-some-cool-article.html`

should be converted to

`<a href="http://www.website.com/article/123-some-cool-article.html">http://www.website.com</a>`

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly, although this would be a trivial patch to Linkify.php.